# How to figure out whether button is continuosly pressed or not in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qpushbutton

For my application, I need my lift system to go up as long as the button is pressed and it should stop when I don't press the button.

clicked() function is not functional for this purpose. However pressed() and released() functions also didn't work.

I snipped related section of my code below. My aim is to print "Pressed" text as long as button is pressed

```
def __init__(self):
    manual_button = QPushButton('Lift Button')
    manual_button.pressed.connect(press_function)
    self.manual_grid.addWidget(manual_button, 0, 1)

def press_function(self):
    print('pressed')
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that `pressed` and `released` didn't work? And, most importantly, why do you need to print continuously when the button is pressed? What is you actual purpose?

Comment: Hello @musicamante,

Because I tried to accomplish it without Timer.  And I was not able to capture the pressing duration.

My purpose is to continuously publish data to one ROS node. I have 2 buttons, first one is for lifting up and second one is for lifting down. If I press the first button data should be 1, if I press the second button data should be -1, if I don't press the button data should be 0.
 
As a solution I added a thread to my function to continuosly publish the data. In thread I added isDown() function inside the if statements to check whether buttons are pressed or not.

Comment: Threads should *never* access UI elements, as they are not thread safe. This is of utmost importance for creation and modification, but also even for property reading, which is not always reliable. If you need to read properties of widgets, you can only do it from the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `pressed` and `released` signals to start/stop a `QTimer`.  Something like...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import(QTimer)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import(QApplication, QPushButton)

def button_pressed(timer):
    timer.start(100)

def button_released(timer):
    timer.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pb = QPushButton("Press")
    timer = QTimer()
    pb.pressed.connect(lambda checked = False: button_pressed(timer))
    pb.released.connect(lambda checked = False: button_released(timer))
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print('Button Pressed'))
    pb.show()
    app.exec_()
```